# Get rid of Iterator in a List in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator

**Current Situation:**
I am using the combinations method in order to create all possible combinations of list elements.

```
//Input list
lf  : List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,2), (a,1), (b,2), (b,1))
//For loop
for (len <- (0 to lf.length).toList) yield {lf.combinations(len)}
//> res1: List[Iterator[List[(Char, Int)]]] = List(non-empty iterator, non-empty
//|  iterator, non-empty iterator, empty iterator, empty iterator)
```

combinations returns *Iterator[List[A]]*

**What I need**

1. List item `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`
2. Ignore empty iterator

How could I get rid of the Iterator?

Comment: Also beware that `combinations` removes duplicates, so if the same value appears twice in your list then it may not behave the way that you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all `combinations()`, from single elements to the full `List`, in a `List`.

```
lf.indices.flatMap(x => lf.combinations(x+1)).toList
//res0: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = List(
//   List((a,2)), List((a,1)), List((b,2)), List((b,1))
// , List((a,2), (a,1)), List((a,2), (b,2)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((b,2), (b,1))
// , List((a,2), (a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2), (a,1), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,2), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,2), (b,1))
// , List((a,2), (a,1), (b,2), (b,1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use .toList

```
val lf  : List[(Char, Int)] = List(('a',2), ('a',1), ('b',2), ('b',1))

for (len <- (0 to lf.length).toList) yield {lf.combinations(len)}.filter(_.length > 0).toList
```

Comment: This answer is confusing. The `filter` does not do anything and the `{}` make it appear that `filter` and `toList` are applied to the result of the `for` when in fact they are applied to the `yield` expression.

Comment: This also creates `List[List[List[(Char, Int)]]]`.

Comment: As already commented this answer leads to an unerwartet result: List[List[List[(Char, Int)]]]